# Yubyte DB YCQL unable to source using COPY command

Tags: yugabytedb

Unable to source large csv file containing blob in ycql.
global name 'BlobType' is not defined,  given up without retries

Comment: Can you describe the exact steps that you took? How big is the blob? And what error did you get?

Comment: "global name 'BlobType' is not defined" this is the error i was getting while trying to source large csv file in yugabyte.

Comment: Please also answer my other questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It was getting timeout for sourcing large csv file , Anyways it got solved by adding CHUNKSIZE=1;